# Jquery: slideshow an absolute positioned div

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script> 
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#flip").click(function(){
                    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style> 
            #panel,#flip {
                padding:5px;
                text-align:center;
                background-color:#e5eecc;
                border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
            }
            #panel {
                position:absolute;
                padding:50px;
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
        <div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
        <div id="goDown">dddddddd</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/wsbctu4h/5/)

I want the third div "goDown" to go down the same time the "panel" div apears.It works
without "position:absolute;" but i need it like this. My question is if this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need absolute positioning? Using position absolute is changing the stack order of your divs so I need to understand why you want to use position: absolute... Here is a demo of your code for other developers if they are to help: http://jsfiddle.net/4wam67n9/1/

Comment: By trying to answer your question i found the answer to mine. I don't need to use "position:absolute" anymore. I was making my life harder. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/wsbctu4h/6/)**

js

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var h = $("#panel").outerHeight();
      $("#flip").click(function () {
          $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
          $("#goDown").animate({marginTop: h}, "slow");
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wsbctu4h/). Is this what you wanted?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="flip">Click to slide down panel</div>
    <div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
    <div id="goDown">dddddddd</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#panel,#goDown,#flip {
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#e5eecc;
    border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel {
    position:absolute;
    padding:50px;
    display:none;
}
#goDown {
    position:absolute;
    padding:50px;
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#flip").click(function(){
         var left = $("#panel").css('width'); // get left panel width
         left = parseInt(left.substr(0, left.indexOf('p')),10); //parse it so we can add to it
         $("#goDown").css('margin-left', (left + 100)+'px'); // add 100 (double the padding)
         $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
         $("#goDown").slideDown("slow");
     });
 });
```

Comment: No, i wanted the result to be exactly this: jsfiddle.net/4wam67n9/1

Comment: ah, I guess I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer.Very simple and ugly

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideDown("slow");
    $('#goDown').css({"margin-top":"120px"});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a much more compact way to do it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#flip").click(function () {
        $(this).next().toggle("easeInOutQuint");
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/wsbctu4h/2/)
The script finds the next thing in the HTML and toggles it